# Horizontal alignment of plots (pgfplots)

Tags: pgfplots, positioning

I have 4 plots generated by pgfplots that I would like vertically and horizontally aligned. They are all included in my main file via `\input`. Due to memory constraints two of them live in one file while the other two are in separate files. I use the `externalize` feature to prevent re-compilation of the plots every time I compile my document. Here's the part of my main file that pertains to the plots:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\input{Inhalt/Abbildungen/LaTeX/TailDependence_Funktionen}
  \input{Inhalt/Abbildungen/LaTeX/Scatterplot_norm}
  \input{Inhalt/Abbildungen/LaTeX/Scatterplot_t}

\caption{Funktionen und Scatterplot}
\end{figure}
```

I've tried various combinations of `trim axis left`and `trim axis right`. All plots are scaled to 0.81. I can get close by using `trim axis left`on the plots on the left side and `trim axis right`on the plots on the right side. So my `tikzpicture environments` look like this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.81, trim axis left]
```

or

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.81, trim axis right]
```

This is what it looks like right now:

[image: Current situation]

I would like the y-axes of the two plots on the left aligned as well as the y-axes of the two plots on the right. At the moment the alignment is a little off.

As my plots rely on external data files I'm not sure how to provide a MWE but will try my best if necessary.

Comment: If you cannot do anything else, you can play around with the y label style with introducing shifts.

Comment: Did you look at the `groupplot` functions in `pgfplots`?  You might find it easier to group all four plots in pgf and then externalize the result (to avoid recompilation) - or make a PDF with an external tool, like "lattice" graphics in R, which excels at multiple plots like this.

Comment: I might try that. However, I'm not sure whether it would cause the memory limit to be exceeded.

Comment: The mis-alignnments are probably due to text, both the y axis label and x axis numbers which go over the edge.  You could create a uniform size for all the plots by placing a \coordinate outside the axis at a uniform distance in opposite corners.

Comment: Possible duplicate [Drawing curves and multiple y-axes in one plot with pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99181/how-to-align-pgfplot-subplots)

Comment: try using the style `ylabel absolute` . This will position the y labels at exactly the same distance to the axis (without respecting any tick labels). It is essentially the same idea as suggested by @percusse except that this uses a predefined distance.

Answer (score 1):

You can fine tune the offsets to be big enough without excess white space using \draw.

[image: aligned]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{4 in}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[ylabel={Y label},xmin=-1,xmax=1,width=3in,height=2in]
    \addplot coordinates {(-1,-1) (1,1)};
    \coordinate (NE) at (rel axis cs: 1,1);% upper right corner of axis
  \end{axis}
  \path (-15mm,-5mm) ($(NE)+(3mm,2mm)$);
  %\draw[red] (-15mm,-5mm) rectangle ($(NE)+(3mm,2mm)$);% to fine tune offsets
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[xmin=-10,xmax=10,width=3in,height=2in]
    \addplot coordinates {(-10,-10) (10,10)};
    \coordinate (NE) at (rel axis cs: 1,1);
  \end{axis}
  \path (-15mm,-5mm) ($(NE)+(3mm,2mm)$);
  %\draw[red] (-15mm,-5mm) rectangle ($(NE)+(3mm,2mm)$);% to fine tune offsets
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```